# Confused about Vigenère cipher implementation in Java

Tags: java, encryption, vigenere

Please can someone explain the line of code highlighted below. I don't understand at all how this line works.

You can use this example to help me:

```
input:   ATTACK  
keyword: LEMON  
res:     LXFOPV
```

I don't understand how that line helps encode `A` to `L` and other letter...
ACSII involvement?

```
static String encrypt(String text, final String key) {
    String res = "";
    text = text.toUpperCase();
    for (int i = 0, j = 0; i < text.length(); i++) {
        char c = text.charAt(i);
        if (c < 'A' || c > 'Z') continue;
 ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//please someone explain this line
        res += (char)((c + key.charAt(j) - 2 * 'A') % 26 + 'A'); 
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

        j = ++j % key.length();
    }
    return res;
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### Background

The code uses the ASCII value of the letters. The letters A-Z are ASCII values 65-90.

The idea is to add the two letters together, but wrap around if the values goes above 90 (known as [modular arithmetic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_arithmetic)). So 91 should actually be 65 (i.e. `Z + 1 = A`).

Java provides a `%` operator for doing modular arithmetic (`x % n`). However, this is designed to work on a range of numbers 0→*n-1*. So, if we subtract 65 from each of our letters, we are then working in the range 0→25. This allows us to use the modulus operator (`x % 26`).

This is what the code is doing:

```
c + key.charAt(j) - 2 * 'A'
```

This part adds the two letters together, but also subtracts 65 from each of them. It may be easier to understand if written as:

```
(c - 'A') + (key.charAt(j) - 'A')
```

*You'll notice that you can do `- 'A'` as a convenient way of doing `- 65`.*

Now we have a value that's zero-based, but possibly larger than 25. So we then modulo it:

```
(c + key.charAt(j) - 2 * 'A') % 26
```

We then need to add 65 back to the value, to bring it back into the A-Z range for ASCII:

```
(c + key.charAt(j) - 2 * 'A') % 26 + 'A'
```

The only remaining step is to cast this to a `char`, since the result is an `int` by default:

```
res += (char)((c + key.charAt(j) - 2 * 'A') % 26 + 'A');
```

### Example

If the input is `ATTACK` and the keyword is `LEMON`, then at some point we are going to have to consider the input letter `T` (ASCII 84) and the key letter `M` (ASCII 77).

Subtracting 65 from each, we have T=19 and M=12. Added together, we get 31.

`31 % 26 = 5`. So we then calculate `5+65=70`, which is the ASCII value for  `F`.

Comment: Nice explanation, but Java's `char` holds a Unicode/UTF-16 code unit, not an ASCII codepoint. Yes, for the characters in question, all the values are the same but thinking the range of `char` is 0-127 or that any 16-bit value is a valid UTF-16 code unit could lead to bugs. Arithmetic can work over only certain ranges of `char` values.

Comment: @TomBlodget Yes, good point. It doesn't affect this code, but it is helpful if the OP doesn't misunderstand what a `char` can hold.